# ManyToMany mapping issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to do a many-to-many mapping between 2 tables **users** and **products**. I wrote their entities and repositories but still the application is giving error. Please help me out if you can, thanks in advance.

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.poc.joins.entities.User.users in com.poc.joins.entities.Product.users
```

The code snippets are

**User**

```
package com.poc.joins.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_products",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "username")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id")})
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
}
// Getter, setters, constructors are not shown here
```

**Product**

```
package com.poc.joins.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String p_name;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Float price;
    private Float total;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet< >();
}
// Getter, setters, constructors are not shown here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the owned entity (`Product`), you pass in the field that owns the relationship (in the `User` entity):

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet< >();
```

Originally you told the Persistence provider to look for the field called `users` in the `User` entity which would hold all the information about the relationship (@JoinTable etc.)

Comment: That worked like a charm! thanks a bunch for that. If you have any spare time, could you explain a bit as to why we need to do that change?